# what is wrong with my system, unable to unpack dict. having unicode objects?

Tags: python, ubuntu, dictionary, argument-unpacking

```
In [1]: l1 = lambda *args, **kw: args

In [2]: l1(**{'name':'hello'})
Out[2]: ()

In [3]: l1(**{u'name':'hello'})
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

/home/sma/<ipython console> in <module>()
```

I've some problem with Python unable to pass/unpack the dictionary elements to the functions... might be my python is corrupted or system is broken don't know but this is strange

I'm using 
python 2.6.2 on Ubuntu 9.04 Jaunty Jacob

Comment: I have Python 2.6.1 on Mac OS X and I get the error: *TypeError: `<lambda>()` keywords must be strings*

Comment: I've another system installed ubuntu 10.10 it works with python 2.6.5 !!! its really crazy - can't understand what's wrong with unicode !!!

Comment: Works fine for me, Python 2.6.6 on Ubuntu 10.10. I presume it's a bug which was fixed (i.e. allow key names as `basestr`, including `unicode`, not just `str`) somewhere between 2.6.1 and 2.6.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be related with this [(non-)bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue1712419) (old), but there are even [more](http://bugs.python.org/issue2646) [bug reports](http://bugs.python.org/issue4978) and it really seems to be fixed from 2.6.5 on only.

That is all I found and I don't have more insight into Python to explain how or why ;)

Comment: got the answer to my question !!